# Presented view controller change value of main view

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, presentviewcontroller

I have a two view controller.

Lets say VC1 and VC2, I am presenting view VC2 from VC1 and sending a NSMutableArray. Like this:

```
let vc2 = VC2()
vc2.array = self.someArray
self.presentViewController(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I write a delegate to notify VC1 when something change. But when VC2 change the value of array and dismiss array at VC1 automatically change. I want to change it only when delegate method called.

I can't figure it out. It doesn't make sense.

Sorry for bad English.

Have a nice day.

Comment: What is the type of `self.someArray`?

Comment: It is NSMutableArray @jtbandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` is called **mutable** for a reason. It can change. When you say `vc2.array = self.someArray`, this is a reference to the same mutable array, not a new copy.

Either use `.copy()` to create a copy, or just use regular Swift arrays (e.g. `[Int]`) which are immutable.

Comment: I have tried but not working. I have object in array, should I create copy of them? Thank you for the answer btw.

Comment: Yes. Even with Swift arrays, if the elements are reference types, you get a shallow copy. Please read [this blog post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) for more information.